# generate debian source packages with install4j

Tags: debian, install4j

Is it possible to generate debian source packages with install4j? I know how to produce nice .deb packages which contain binaries, but I would like to generate something like the following for my application XY:

- XY.dsc
- XY.debian.tar.xz
- XY_all.deb
- XY.orig.tar.gz

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, creating Debian source packages is not supported as of install4j 6.0.